# Python Access Database Query Giving "Data Source Name Not Found"

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

Whenever I attempt to query a file using Python script, I receive the following error

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

[Image of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbsnp.png)

My code is as followings:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect ("DRIVER={ODBCDataFile [Microsoft Access Driver 
(*.mdb, *.accdb)]};DBQ=C:\Users\jmtr\Documents\IRST_old.accdb;")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Name, CAI, Email, SSPLocation, BUNUM from Tbl_SSP")
```

My Access database is "Microsoft Access 2016 32-bit".  I am also using "32-bit" python 2.7.13 and 32-bit PYODBC. And, I have 32-bit drivers set-up in the ODBC Data Source Administrator:

[Image of ODBC 32-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wehn8.png)

I don't understand why I am still receiving this error message?

Answer (score 5):

Connection string is incorrect. There is no `ODBCDataFile` keyword with brackets `[...]`. Simply remove them and assign *DRIVER* to installed ODBC driver as your screenshot shows:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + \
                      "DBQ=C:\\Users\\jmtr\\Documents\\IRST_old.accdb;")
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the requested change and the query is working now! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled `ODBCDataFile` instead of `ODBCFile`.

But in python the character `\` is the escape character in the strings. You need to append the prefix `r"DRIVER..."` to force raw strings, so without missinterpreting the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

First download and install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) if you haven’t.

Then you should install **pyodbc** module.

Now you can connect to access database :

```
ConFileName=(r'c:\mydb\myaccess.mdb')
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + ConFileName + ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

To select from any table in the database please use this simple code :

```
ConFileName=(r'c:\mydb\myaccess.mdb')
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + ConFileName + ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from table1')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    Table1Array.append((row[0],row[1],row[2])
print(str(len(Table1Array))+" records in Table1 loaded successfully.")
```

You can follow this link to get more information about working with MS Access by Pyton :

https://elvand.com/python-and-ms-access/