# Having trouble connecting to MS Access Driver using pyobdc in Python

Tags: python, ms-access, driver, pyodbc

I have 64-bit Python installed on my machine along with 32-bit Microsoft Access. To get the "bits" to match I run `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1` in the Anaconda Prompt. However, when I loop through my drivers only "SQL Server" comes up. Example of the code below...

```
import pyodbc
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
    print(driver)
```

So when I try to connect to the driver an InterfaceError comes up.

```
connStr = (r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
           r'DBQ=P:\DataCompilation\DataCompilationPy\local_access_db\SiteData.accdb;'
          )
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
```

The error says... InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I was able to import .csv data from the same location so the directory is at least not the problem. When I look for solutions they typically advise to have the same bit types for Python and Microsoft Access which I should have. Any advice?

Comment: This answer looks as though it should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117345/python-access-database-query-giving-data-source-name-not-found?rq=1

Comment: For anyone who might be looking at this in the future, I ended up just downloading the 32-bit version of Python because `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1` turned out to be out of date.